# Asp:Login control not redirect properly on second login attempt

Tags: asp.net, login-control

As said in the title Login control i used is not redirecting the same way it does when i log in first time. The problem is the first time i log in the redirect is correct(default.aspx) and after i LogOut and then Login again it takes me to the page i logged out from. I am out of ideas on what to do! Appreciate all help! Thanx!

```
<asp:Login ID="Login1" runat="server" DestinationPageUrl="~/Default.aspx" DisplayRememberMe="False"
TitleText="" UserNameLabelText="Username:" OnAuthenticate="Login1Authenticate" 
FailureText="Incorrect username or password" Width="100%" VisibleWhenLoggedIn="False" 
FailureAction="Refresh"  >
</asp:Login>
```

---

```
protected void Login1Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
{
    var filecontent = Server.MapPath(@"~/App_Data/UsersFile.txt");
    var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filecontent);

    foreach (var line in lines)
    {
        if (line.Contains(@"username"))
        {
            var str = line; int index = str.IndexOf("=", StringComparison.Ordinal);
            var newstr = str.Substring(index + 1);
            Username = newstr.Trim();
        }
        if (line.Contains(@"password"))
        {
            var str = line; int index = str.IndexOf("=", StringComparison.Ordinal);
            var newstr = str.Substring(index + 1);
            Password = newstr.Trim();
        }

        if ((!Login1.UserName.Trim().Equals(Username)) || (!Login1.Password.Trim().Equals(Password))) continue;
        e.Authenticated = true;
        LogUserActions(Username, "Logged in successfully at: ");
        break;
    }

    if (e.Authenticated) return;
    LogUserActions(Username, "Failed to login in at: ");
    LoginStatus1_ModalPopupExtender.Show();
}
```

Comment: after you hit the logout, what does your url look like? and what is the code for your logout?

Comment: That is how the URL looks like when logged out second time:
`http://localhost:59630/WebSite1/login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fWebSite1%2fSummary.aspx%3ftext%3dHotel%2bBangkok&text=Hotel+Bangkok`
And I dont have any event handler for Logout since "LoginStatus1" is a Ajax popupControl controlling the login handling on my website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silly me when not noticing the `Loginstatus` property on the page.
This solved my problem after adding `LogoutAction` and `LogOutURL`.

```
<asp:LoginStatus ID="LoginStatus1" runat="server" 
LogoutAction="RedirectToLoginPage" LogoutPageUrl="~/Login.aspx" />
```